# What is '&' meaning in this php code

Tags: php, wordpress

i using word press, and i try to learn it,
but is see the code which i didn't understand

```
$post = &get_post($id);
```

i see '&' before the get_post,
what is '&' meaning?

thank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you're getting a reference to the result of `get_post($id)`.

In particular you're using the "returning by reference" technique.

[Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) :

> Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to find to which variable a reference should be bound.

---

> The same syntax can be used with functions that return references, and with the new operator (since PHP 4.0.4 and before PHP 5.0.0):
>
> ```
>   <?php
>   $foo =& find_var($bar);
>   ?>
> ```
>
> Since PHP 5, new returns a reference automatically, so using `=&` in this context is deprecated and produces an `E_STRICT` message.

So if you're using `>= PHP 5` it's not a really great idea to use this notation.

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, i'm really happy with this explanation. you include the example of case.. best answer :D

Answer (score 5):

Passing or assigning [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 2):

Now you already know that is for return by reference, next things is the effect of that.
The effect will be this:
Whenever you change $post variable's value, you are actually changing the get_post($id) content. [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) return object having all the info about that post in database.